# Пересечение сферы и треугольника

Tags: геометрия

*Занимаюсь сейчас перемещением сферы в пространстве со столкновениями с другими обьектами. Возникла проблемы с решением задачи про пересечение сферы и треугольника (из которых у меня состоят многогранники).*

Даны координаты центра сферы и ее радиус, а так же три точки треугольника в пространстве. Необходимо узнать, пересекает ли треугольник сферу (своей стороной или площадью).

Еще более формально:
Дана точка O(x0, y0, z0) - центр сферы.
Дано вещественное число r - радиус сферы.
Даны три вершины треугольника: A(x1, y1, z1), B(x2, y2, z2), C(x3, y3, z3).
Необходимо ответить на вопрос: имеет ли треугольник хотя бы одну общую точку со сферой?

Comment: из вашего вопроса ничего не понятно кроме того что вы чем-то занимаетесь, уточните где вы это занимаетесь перемещениями сферы, если есть код то приложите его, иначе вопрос просто закроют из-за недостатка информации :(

Comment: @Andrew, разве на stackoverflow нельзя задавать вопросы, связанные с кодом не напрямую? Мне интереснее решение, чем готовый код на определенном языке, который я скопирую. Можете посоветовать платформу, на которой за четкую постановку задачи вопрос не снимают из-за отсутствия кода?

Comment: можно конечно и не связанный с кодом, но просто очень непонятно что вы делаете, если у вас возникла проблема то есть уже какой-то код наверное

Comment: имхо это нормальный вопрос, и достаточно информации

Comment: @Andrew, по вашему запросу добавил в вопрос конкретики

Comment: http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, похоже, это как раз, что нужно, буду пытаться понять. Большое спасибо!

Comment: еще гуглите: sphere triangle intersection test

Comment: @KingCake [математика у нас разрешена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8683/15479), но некоторым не нравится, когда в вопросе не приведены попытки решения.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik я так понимаю если вопрос будет, например, про все нетривиальные нули дзета-функции Римана его тоже закроют с формулировкой "домашка"

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, скорей всего =/

Comment: выглядит так, что вам нужна сумма минковского, но для трёх измерений. про два можно почитать например тут https://habr.com/ru/post/217645/, а про три кажись пишут вот тут с готовым решением https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionMovingSphereTriangle.pdf

Comment: Найти плоскость, в которой лежит треугольник. Найти пересечение плоскости и сферы. Найти пересечение окружности и треугольника.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ:

1. Сразу проверим, не лежит ли весь треугольник в сфере (ведь тогда он ее точно не пересекает). Для этого сравним расстояние от его вершин до центра сферы с ее радиусом. Если все три точки - внутри, то сразу можно давать ответ 'нет'. Иначе:
2. Найдем ближайшую к центру сферы точку треугольника. Для этого проецируем центр на плоскость треугольника. Если проекция лежит внутри треугольника, то переходим к п.4.
3. Иначе искомая точка лежит на сторонах треугольника. Найдем ее через поиск минимального расстояния до отрезков - тех самых сторон.
4. Проверим, лежит ли найденная точка внутри сферы. Если да, то пересечение есть, иначе - нет.

Comment: Представь, что в п. 4 вся проекция сферы - внутри треугольника... так что способ-то простой - но неправильный.

Comment: @Akina, никак не придумаю случая, в котором пункту 4 мешало бы то, что вся проекция сферы внутри треугольника. Если какая-то его точка лежит внутри сферы, и мы знаем, что хотя бы одна есть снаружи, то треугольник сферу пересекает, разве нет?

Comment: Если вся проекция сферы на плоскость треугольника (большой окружности, параллельной плоскости) лежит внутри треугольника - точек пересечения НЕТ.

Comment: Почему же нет? Например, большой треугольник, разрезающий сферу в пространстве пополам, всю ее проекцию имеет на себе, но пересечения есть. В п.4. написано проверить наличие точки внутри сферы, а не окружности ее проекции

Comment: Приехали... то есть в твоём вопросе сфера - это тонкая оболочка, а вот треугольник - это не только его стороны, но и все внутренние точки??? блин, а указать эту (весьма неочевидную) мелочь в постановке задачи - не? Но если так - то задача-то тривиальна. См. ответ Мирона.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за оценку сложности задачи. Скажите, как изменить следующее предложение условия, чтобы это стало ясно? 
> пересекает ли треугольник сферу (своей стороной или площадью).

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендуемая последовательность действий.

1. Построить плоскость треугольника.
2. Построить проекцию на эту плоскость центра сферы, а затем и окружность пересечения сферы и плоскости.
3. Решить задачу наличия общей точки у треугольника и окружности на плоскости.

Для упрощения расчёта рекомендуется выполнить поворот относительно центра сферы так, чтобы плоскость треугольника была перпендикулярна одной из координатных прямых.

Answer (score 1):

Задачу можно свести к задаче "Определите, если ли общие точки у 2D фигуры и шара".

1. Если все точки 2D фигуры удалены от центра шара на расстояние `<= r`, то 2D фигура находится внутри шара.
2. Если `n` точек внутри, а `k` точек снаружи, где `n > 0` и `k > 0`, то 2D фигура пересекает шар.
3. Осталось рассмотреть случай, когда все точки - снаружи. Очевидно, что пересечение будет лишь в том случае, когда самая близкая к центру окружности точка `ПЛОСКОСТИ ФИГУРЫ` на расстоянии `<= r` и когда эта точка лежит в фигуре. Если предыдущие два условия не были выполнены, то проверяйте, `<= r` все перпендикуляры к отрезкам и врезаются ли эти перпендикуляры в отрезки. Если врезаются, и длина `<= r`(хоть один если найдется такой), то фигура пересекает шар.

Comment: Утверждение (3) - неполно. Что делать, если: все вершинные точки вовне сферы, а самая близкая к центру сферы точка плоскости вовне фигуры? ситуация допускает и наличие, и отсутствие точки пересечения.

Comment: @Akina дополнил

Comment: См. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KvMZ.png

Comment: @Akina В этом случае столкновения не происходит. Если вы даже чуть левее подвинете(чтобы было столкновение), то с моим дополнением по алгоритму выйдет, что общие точки есть